# How to use json object with where clause?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**What I'm trying to achieve**

Find all players which is in the authenticated users team.

**What is the Problem?**

Unable to use the returned json within const findUsers = await User.findAll where clause and I am unsure if this is the correct way.

**Database Tables**

Users Table : id (PK) , etc

Teams: id (PK) , etc

TeamUsers: id , TeamID (Foreign Key) , UserID (Foreign Key) , etc

**Returning Json from FindTeamUsers (Var ob) which is correct**

```
[{"id":2,"TeamID":1,"UserID":1,"createdAt":"2019-08-09","updatedAt":"2019-08-09"},{"id":3,"TeamID":1,"UserID":3,"createdAt":"2019-08-09","updatedAt":"2019-08-09"},{"id":76,"TeamID":1,"UserID":5,"createdAt":"2019-08-22","updatedAt":"2019-08-22"}]
```

Below is the Route that I am currently using using Nodejs, ExpressJS

```
router.get('/Team', auth, async function(req, res) {

 // -- Get the Users team that is currently Authenticated (req.user.id (auth) )
     const findTeam = await TeamUsers.findOne({
        where: {
          UserID: req.user.id
        }
      });

      //If the User has a team
      if (findTeam) {

  // -- Get the players Team Mates who have the matching TeamID
        const findTeamUsers = await TeamUsers.findAll({

          where: {
            TeamID: findTeam.TeamID
          }

        });
//Store the object and Display in JSON FORMAT
         var ob = JSON.stringify(findTeamUsers);
         console.log(ob);

        if (!findTeamUsers) {
          console.log('error');
        } else {
          //find the Users Details From the Users Table Model
          //findTeamUsers - Is an array of each record found from const findTeamUsers = await TeamUsers.findAll
          const findUsers = await User.findAll({
            where: {
              id: ob.UserID
            }
          });

          res.status(200).json(findUsers);


        }
      }

    });
```

Comment: What error are you getting? `findTeam is undefined` perhaps?

Comment: @silencedogood  Error: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value . this is from ob.id within FindUsers . FindTeamUsers work correctly .

Comment: had to change my code it was findteamusers.UserID , should have been ob.id . ob being the object and id refers to the user id within the USers table

Comment: looking at your `ob` object, `id` should be accessed as `ob[0].id`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ob` is a `string` so `ob.UserID` is `undefined`. `findTeamUsers` (`FindTeamUsers` result) is an array of object so `findTeamUsers.UserID` would be `undefined` too. (array `findTeamUsers` does not have property `UserID`).

You can pass [an `array` of UserIDs to search multiple elements](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-usage.html#-code-findall--code----search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database) (if you want to find for all `UserID`s in the array):

```
User.findAll({
  where: {
    id: findTeamUsers.map(o => o.UserID)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I have tried this there now , im receiving this error . TypeError: ob.map is not a function

Comment: whops didn't notice, your `ob` is `string`, `findTeamUsers` should be array, use that. updating answer